# Как вывести определенное количество элементов?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть парсер заголовков из RSS, как вывести только первые, допустим, 5 заголовков и в консоли выводилось бы в формате 
Feed: источник новости
Date: когда вышла новость
Link: ссылка на новость

вот то, как я начал это делать

```py
import feedparser

# Function to fetch the rss feed and return the parsed RSS
def parseRSS(rss_url):
    return feedparser.parse(rss_url) 

# Function grabs the rss feed headlines (titles) and returns them as a list
def getHeadlines(rss_url):
    headlines = []

    feed = parseRSS(rss_url)
    for newsitem in feed['items']:
        headlines.append(newsitem['title'])

    return headlines

# A list to hold all headlines
allheadlines = []

# List of RSS feeds that we will fetch and combine
newsurls = {
    'googlenews':       'https://news.google.com/rss?hl=ru&gl=RU&ceid=RU:ru'
}

# Iterate over the feed urls
for key,url in newsurls.items():
    # Call getHeadlines() and combine the returned headlines with allheadlines
    allheadlines.extend( getHeadlines(url))


# Iterate over the allheadlines list and print each headline
for hl in allheadlines:
    print(hl)
print("link: {0}" .format(newsurls))
```

Comment: Вывести определенное количество чего-то всегда можно срезом, и вы даже в коде его используете. Например `headlines[0:5]` - это список из 5 элементов. Можете перебирать при выводе не весь список, а только эти 5 элементов. Допустим,`for headline in hedlines[0:5]`

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, `0` опциальный, просто `headlines[:5]` :)

Comment: @gil9red да, но explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров, не в этом случае, это больше вкусовщина. Ведь и так понятно, что `headlines[:5]` это `headlines[0:5]`, так зачем 0 писать. А вот `headlines[5:]` это `headlines[5:len(headlines)]`. Но вы ведь не будете писать `headlines[5:len(headlines)]`, правда ли? :) Кст, с той же логикой `range(5)` тоже нужно писать как `range(0, 5)`

Comment: @gil9red желательно даже range(0, 5, 1) ☝️

Comment: @Эникейщик как и `x[0:1:1]`, я прошу заметить. Не знаю, мне нравится для среза с 0 элемента явно указывать 0. Да и в `range(0, 5)` тоже ничего плохого не вижу :)